# SQL query looking for assistance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a a bunch of columns in my table:

- TransactionID
- TransactionName
- TransactionDate
- TransactionValue
- TransactionQTY

What I'm trying to do is look for the most recent TransactionDate and take that TransactionValue (the thing here is that the latest value might be a negative number, so I need to convert it to positive). I'm actually working on a report in Access but I've been working out of SQL to get this query to work.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
     TransactionID, TransactionName, Max(abs(TransactionValue)) AS 
     HighestPrice, MAX(TransactionDate) AS LatestDate
FROM tblTransactionRecords
WHERE TransactionQTY<>0
ORDER BY TransactionName
```

But this doesn't give me that information. It only grabs the MAX Value of that column rather than grabbing the Max Value where the TransactionDate is the most recent.

Comment: so do you have the multiple entries of same transaction id in your table? or you just want to select only one row with latest transaction date from the above query?

Comment: Yes I have a TransactionID column that has about 30 different ID's and many instances of each. My end goal is to have only one ID for each different ID with the highest TransactionValue. ID=177 TransValue=$200.00, ID=188 TransValue = $500. and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `GROUP BY` statement between the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY` indicating on which columns you want to group.

Answer (score 1):

> look for the most recent TransactionDate and take that
>   TransactionValue (the thing here is that the latest value might be a
>   negative number, so I need to convert it to positive)

<=>

> take the absolute value of the TransactionValue for the most recent TransactionDate

<=>

```
SELECT abs(TransactionValue)
FROM tblTransactionRecords
WHERE TransactionDate = Max(TransactionDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there can be multiple records with the same *TransactionDate*, filter by date and keep only the highest value:

```
SELECT TOP 1
 TransactionID, TransactionName, abs(TransactionValue) AS HighestPrice, TransactionDate 
 FROM tblTransactionRecords 
 WHERE TransactionDate=MAX(TransactionDate)
 ORDER BY abs(TransactionValue) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Having` clause

```
SELECT 
     TransactionID, TransactionName, Max(abs(TransactionValue)) AS 
     HighestPrice, MAX(TransactionDate) AS LatestDate
FROM tblTransactionRecords
GROUP BY TransactionID
Having TransactionDate = MAX(TransactionDate) and TransactionQTY<>0
```